# Scraping Content using scrapy giving null sometimes and correct result othertimes

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some content from the site http://www.jabong.com/Puma-Wirko-Ind-Black-Sneakers-187839.html using scrapy.
The script below runs successfully, but some of the variables(brand, mrp, pcode, pdesc) are getting null values sometimes:

```
 from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
 from scrapy.http import Request
from tutorial.items import DmozItem




class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "dmozjabong"
allowed_domains = ["jabong.com"]
start_urls = [

 "http://www.jabong.com/Puma-Wirko-Ind-Black-Sneakers-187839.html"
]


def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)  
item = DmozItem()
item['title'] =' '.join(hxs.select('/html/head/title').extract()).strip()   
item['link'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="refurl"]/@value').extract()).strip()    
item['kwords'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('/html/head/meta[7]/@content').extract()).strip()  
item['mdes'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('/html/head/meta[6]/@content').extract()).strip()  
item['pname'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="qa-title-product"]/text()').extract()).strip()  
item['pcode'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//div[@id="productInfo"]//table/tr[8]/td[2]/text()').extract()).strip()  
item['pdesc'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="productInfo"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p/text()').extract()).strip()  
item['pimg'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/img/@src').extract()
item['brand'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img/@alt').extract()).strip()
counter = 0
for image_data in item['pimg']:
        with open('image_' + str(counter) + '.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(image_data)
        counter += 1
item['bread'] = ' '.join(map(unicode.strip, hxs.select('id("breadcrumbs")//text()').extract())).strip()
item['listprice'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="before_price"]/span[2]/span/text()').extract()).strip()  
item['mrp'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="price_div"]/span[2]/strike/text()').extract()).strip()
print item
```

Comment: Could it probably due to the non-existence of the searched path in the page?

Comment: But it's giving results sometimes.

Comment: Yes, that could probably due to the page being not consistent, some pages having those paths, others don't.

Comment: I'm trying for the same product url again and again.

Comment: I have to agree with user2747776 here, I have the same issue. Different running of the same spider gives very different results on the same page. Sometimes it does scrap the info, sometimes it scraps empty strings... and when I click on the url from the output, I do get a source code that is clearly scrapable

Answer (score 0):

There could also be some small "mistakes" or code variations in the html code, so scrapy then doesn't return anything. The best way to find out should be trying 1 or 2 links which work, and 1 or 2 that return empty information, and then look for differences in code or smth.

Comment: Like I said before, the script for the same product url is sometimes giving null values and sometimes correct string values.